# Timeout uncontrolled overridden function in Python

Tags: python

There have been some questions discussing this but none have the set of constraints that I have so maybe someone will come with a good idea.

Basically I need to set-up a timeout for a Python function under the following constraints:

1. Cross-platform (i.e. no signal.ALARM)
2. Not Python 3 (I can assume Python >= 2.7.9)
3. Only the function needs to be timed-out, can't just exit the entire program.
4. I have absolutely no control over the called function, i.e. it's a callback using an abstract interface (using derived classes and overrides). Other people will be writing these callback functions and the assumption is that they're idiots.

Example code:

```
class AbstractInterface(Object):
    def Callback(self):
        # This will be overridden by derived classes.
        # Assume the implementation cannot be controlled or modified.
        pass

...

def RunCallbacks(listofcallbacks):
    # This is function I can control and modify
    for cb in listofcallbacks:
        # The following call should not be allowed to execute
        # for more than X seconds. If it does, the callback should
        # be terminated but not the entire iteration
        cb.Callback()
```

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> Other people will be writing these callback functions and the assumption is that they're idiots.

You really shouldn't execute code from people you consider 'idiots'.

However, I came up with one possibility shown below (only tested in python3 but should work in python2 with minor modifications).

> Warning: This runs every callback in a new process, which is terminated after the specified timeout.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time

def callback(i):
    while True:
        print("I'm process {}.".format(i))
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(1, 11):
        p = Process(target=callback, args=(i,))
        p.start()
        time.sleep(2) # Timeout
        p.terminate()
```

Comment: > You really shouldn't execute code from people you consider 'idiots'.

That's not really possible, I'm writing a framework that provides an API for other people to build on. It's like writing software with a plugin platform - you don't know who'll be writing the plugins so you can't assume they know how to code.

Anyway - I've thought about forking, The main problem (other than the process creation overhead and the POSIX/Windows differences) is that you need to use complex IPCs (I forgot to mention in my code that the "self" pointer is used).